# How to set the RootViewController to a Grouped Table in SplitViewController

Tags: uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Instead of the plain type of table I want  a Grouped one in the RootViewController.Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You create xib design for RootViewController and in attributes inspector change tableview style to grouped .Its work well

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to **viewDidLoad** of **RootViewController.m**

```
[self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

this will change the tableview style.